# C++ Polymorphism using pure virtual classes and references

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I get an `error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ...`

for

```
void foo(const Abstract& input)
{
    // just an example, this condition is returned by another function
    bool condition = true;
    // Key point: I want this decision to be done inside.
    const Abstract& p = condition ? B() : input;
    p.f();
}
```

I know this is not ideal as the caller should be in charge of this. But this would mean to change plenty of callers in my codebase. This is a reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Abstract
{
    virtual void f() const = 0;
};

struct A: public Abstract
{
    void f() const { std::cout << "Aaa" << std::endl;}
};

struct B: public Abstract
{
    void f() const { std::cout << "VBB" << std::endl;}
};

void foo(const Abstract& input)
{
    // just an example, this condition is returned by another function
    bool condition = true;
    // Key point: I want this decision to be done inside.
    const Abstract& p = condition ? B() : input;
    p.f();
}

int main()
{
  A a;
  foo (a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is a bit technical. You might know every expression in C++ has a [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category): for object types, an lvalue names an existing object, a prvalue can be used to create an object of its type, and an xvalue is like an lvalue but allows the object to be moved from.

In your example, `B()` is a prvalue and `input` is an lvalue. But the conditional expression `condition ? B() : input` needs to have just one value category. This keeps the C++ language rules consistent, plus it would be impractical to define and determine how things work if an expression sometimes names an existing object and sometimes initializes a new object. So [the rules for the conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) say that if either `Y` or `Z` is a prvalue, then `X ? Y : Z` is also a prvalue. So `condition ? B() : input` is a prvalue, which means it never actually names the existing object `input`, but might be used to create an object initialized from `input`.

And a prvalue creates objects using the expression's type. The type of `X ? Y : Z` is the "common type" of `Y` and `Z`. The common type of `B` and `const Abstract` is `Abstract`, since we can't guarantee that the result is a `B`. So the expression `condition ? B() : input` could in theory be used to create an object of type `Abstract`. But of course no such objects can ever be created.

Also, if we had this exact example except that class `Abstract` were not actually abstract, then the statement

```
const Abstract& p = condition ? B() : input;
```

would silently slice an object, and lose all the polymorphism! With `condition` true, it would create a temporary `B`, then create a temporary `Abstract` by slicing that `B`. With `condition` false, it would create a temporary `Abstract` by slicing `input`. In both cases, the binding to reference `p` would then extend the lifetime of the temporary `Abstract` object up to the `}` which ends the scope of `p`.

So the simplest way to get around this is probably to make sure your `B` object expression is an lvalue:

```
B b;
const Abstract& p = condition ? b : input;
```

Or if the default constructor of `B` is expensive or has undesirable side effects when it's not going to be used, maybe something like:

```
std::optional<B> b;
const Abstract& p = condition ? b.emplace() : input;
```